# Response too large to return. Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration

Tags: google-bigquery

I am getting following error when running sql script with two table join.

table_a has 603388514 records left join with table_b with 11147 records.

Total number of columns which I am selecting in this select statement are 147 columns.

"
**Response too large to return. Consider specifying a destination table in your job configuration.**"

Any suggestion / help how to overcome this error message?

Comment: You should target the output of the query into a table - using the `CREATE TABLE` keyword or change the query settings if using the UI. This will store the output in a table which you can then read data from.

Comment: Jeremy's comment is the real answer here. However you meant not to store the output and just want to see some data in output, just limit your source tables with "limit clause" to test out your query logic.